# How to set php cron job?

Tags: php, windows, cron

I am using windows server 2003.

I set a cron job, open IE explorer and run cron.php file.

Basically, what the cron.php does is just send email to my own email address. I set it run every 2 minutes and run for 2 hours. I start the cron services, and I received the first email, but after that, I waited few hours, I am still didn't receive the second email. Anyone can help me?

Comment: How did you set it up to run every 2 minutes?

Comment: A cron job, that does not run every x minutes? Maybe something is wrong configured and the job ends after one repetition. I was never confronted with this kind of problem.

Comment: @Silentghost, sure? Doesn't CronJob belong to serverfault due to the fact it is linked to administration?

Comment: @Dominic: There is an advanced button, i click on that, and set it run every 2 minutes, and in the desciprtion itself, it shows: Schedule: every 2 minutes from bla bla bla...

Comment: @SilentGhost: I was hesitated, where should I post this question, and I dont want to post 2 places with same question.

Comment: @daemonfire: i follow this: http://drupal.org/node/31506

Comment: @flashnewbie,I assumed you use a unix system, sorry, I could not help you with windows

Comment: Is this - by any chance - a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587878/php-send-email-via-cronjob-and-set-amount-of-email-send-per-mins?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably due to the fact that CRON doesn't run on WINDOWS unless you install a CRON for Windows like [CRONw](http://cronw.sourceforge.net/) or such like programs. If that's not an option I think you would need to set up your script to use [Scheduled Tasks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) and follow something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295386/how-to-run-a-php-file-in-schedule-task).

Hope this helps